# Django ModeForm: no fields error

Tags: django, django-forms

I have used the code in django 1.6 but when trying it in django 1.8.6 I get:

```
AttributeError: 'SignupDataForm' object has no attribute 'fields'
```

at this line, but also generaly whenever asking for fields:

```
 merged_field_order = list(self.fields.keys())
```

My SignupDataForm is a child declared like this:

```
class SignupDataForm(BaseUserDataForm):
    reg_user_badge = forms.CharField(label="Give Points to a Friend",required=False,widget = TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username (optional)'}),validators=[validate_friendname])

class Meta(BaseUserDataForm.Meta):
    model = UserData
    fields = BaseUserDataForm.Meta.fields + ('terms_conditions',)
    #terms_conditions is also a model field but not added to the parent definition

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(SignupDataForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['terms_conditions'].required = False
    self.fields['gender'].widget = Select(choices=GENDER_CHOICES,attrs={'class':'signup_select',})
    self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['onblur'] ="check_pass()"
    self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['onblur'] ="check_pass()"


def clean(self):
    #clean overwrite
```

What is weird is that if I use the parent form everything works fine, I get no error. Also if I place a print fields in the META declaration the tuple with fields is there. The shortend code for the parent is here:

```
class BaseUserDataForm(forms.ModelForm):
    url = forms.CharField(max_length = 30, label="Don't type here (anti spam protection)",validators=[validate_name_honeypots])

class Meta:
    model = UserData
    fields = ('****model fields named without terms_conditions field****')

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(BaseUserDataForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

The error occurs in another child:

```
class BaseSignupForm(SignupDataForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label=_("Username"),
                           max_length=get_username_max_length(),
                           min_length=app_settings.USERNAME_MIN_LENGTH,
                           widget=forms.TextInput(
                               attrs={'placeholder':
                                      _('Username'),
                                      'autofocus': 'autofocus'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'type': 'email',
           'placeholder': _('E-mail address')}))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        email_required = kwargs.pop('email_required',
                                app_settings.EMAIL_REQUIRED)
        self.username_required = kwargs.pop('username_required',
                                        app_settings.USERNAME_REQUIRED)
        super(BaseSignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # field order may contain additional fields from our base class,
        # so take proper care when reordering...
        field_order = ['email', 'username']

        merged_field_order = list(self.fields.keys())
```

Does anybody know what am I doing wrong?

UPDATE - SOLVED:
Solved. Not an python ModelForm or allauth issue at all. There was a form below, partially wrapped and partially commented that I didn't see and it caused an intendention error that manifest it such a weird manner ....

Comment: The example code you show seems unlikely; you have classes with no methods, and module-level functions with ‘self’ as the first parameter. That makes it likely there are other differences I don't know about. Can you construct an example and run it, to make sure the same code will work that way for us, and then place *that exact code* in the question instead?

Comment: There are methods however non of the are used, the code breaks during initialization of BaseSignupForm. But you are right that there is more going on. I discarded and deleted my initial thought that this is a 3rd party module issue. So, now I am more sure it actually is a issue for django-allauth during Signupview dispatch method. I posted the question to allauth github. I leave this one open, till I am completly sure that it is a allauth issue.

Comment: I tried to use older versions of django-allauth, some where I used this code before. It didn't change, big is still there. I am confused. I don't get it at all ...